# Access 2014 SQL update table value from unbound form

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a value in a table from an unbound form. The user needs to choose the product name, enter a sales value and then the value updates the correct record in the table. At present I have:

```
UPDATE tblStock
    SET tblStock.Sold = [Forms]![frmItemsSold]![Text3]
    WHERE ((([tblStock]![ProductName]=[Forms]![frmItemsSold]![Combo1])));
```

The form is frmItemsSold and Combo1 on the form has the product name. Text3 on the form contains the sold value which should update the correct record in the Sold field in tblStock. At present my code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you call this code? any error message?

Comment: Is your combobox a single column? If you used a wizard, it likely has a hidden ID field whose value is returned when using the control reference `[Forms]![frmItemsSold]![Combo1]`. Look at the row source of the combobox. Does it call more than one column? It would be helpful to know whether the code runs, what errors are thrown, what results you get, and what results you expect.